# SyntaxHighlighter theme for Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

I've been searching around the internet, but I can't find a Dreamweaver theme that I like. So now I was wondering if any one of you knew of a theme which looks just like this: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/themes/rdark.html

Comment: use a proper editor ... Notepad (Win) or Textmate (Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit | Preferences | Code Coloring and you can set the colors to whatever you want, language by language.